# What is the simplest main() method for a Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, program-entry-point

I wrote the following, but it exits immediately:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/springtests/test01.xml");
}
```

`test01.xml` contains multiple beans with some threads (daemons) which connects to the network etc.

How to wait or something?

Answer (score 4):

All you are doing is creating an object here. You need to retrieve the beans and then use them. For example

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/springtests/test01.xml");
MyClass myObj= MyClass.class.cast(ctx.getBean("myBeanName"));         
myObj.doStuff();
```

If you want more help then post what is in your test01.xml

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree with most of the recommendations in the other answers, I think your main method is ok as it is.  The only thing you need to change is make at least one of your worker threads non-daemon.

From Thread.setDaemon Java doc:

> The Java Virtual Machine exits when the only threads running are all daemon threads.

Also make sure all your threads are started during the init method (or afterPropertiesSet) of the bean and does not require a that the bean be started (implementing the life cycle interface).  The way you have it coded all your beans will be initialized but not started.

Answer (score 1):

> How to wait or something?

I've used something like the following pattern.   My `Main` thread starts the context and then waits for someone else to call `Main.shutdownLatch.countDown()` command to tell it to close the context and exit.  I usually do this with a JMX command.

```
public static CountDownLatch shutdownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context =
       new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/springtests/test01.xml");
    try {
        shutdownLatch.await();
    } finally {
        context.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyone want to explain the -1?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `context.registerShutdownHook()` to ensure [that the beans in the applicationContext are shut down properly](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-shutdown), but you still need to ensure that the main thread does not exit if the applicationContext only starts daemon threads.

A better strategy would be for `main()` to retrieve some bean from the context that it can call `bean.startApp()` on, to kick things off - or have at least one of the threads started in the context be non-daemon.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your beans implement `ApplicationListener<ContextStartedEvent>` i.e:

```
@Override
public final void onApplicationEvent(ContextStartedEvent event) {...
```

and maybe also `ExitCodeGenerator`:

```
@Override
public int getExitCode() {
```

Then your main method could be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(AppConfig.class, args)) {
        context.start();
        System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(context));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do perform the logic in separate thread after initializing spring context. As the new thread starts that can wait on a condition and main thread will finish while your logic still running in another thread. That thread can be stopped by updating variable value via JMX.

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/springtests/test01.xml");
MyClass myObj= MyClass.class.cast(ctx.getBean("myBeanName"));  

ExecutorService executor= Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.submit(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
//Update the value of this variable via jmx
while(<SomeAtomicBooleanValueCheck>)
{
                myObj.doStuff();
}
                            }
        })
```